# keep a div to the bottom of the page until scroll gets to a certain position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following setup:

- A big html page (so scroll is there)
- Inside it near the bottom a div... let's call it positionDiv: `<div id="positionDiv">Lalala</div>`
- Another div called lets say... floatingDiv: `<div id="floatingDiv">Lalala</div>`

What I need to do is to keep `floatingDiv` to the bottom of the page (easy doable with a position: fixed) until it gets (after scrolling) on top of the `positionDiv` (here the position fixed fails since the div will stay at the bottom forever).

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery exposes an [offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) method which can help here.

EDIT: improved code, [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/barney/mFfM6/4/).

```
$(function fixedUntilPoint(){
  var positionDiv = $('#positionDiv');
  var floatingDiv = $('#floatingDiv');

  function testScrollPosition(){ 
    var positionOffset = positionDiv.offset().top;
    var floatingOffset = floatingDiv.offset().top;

    if(positionOffset <= floatingOffset){
      floatingDiv.css({
        bottom:   'auto',
        position: 'absolute',
        top:      positionDiv.offset().top
      })
    }
    else {
      floatingDiv.css({
        bottom:   0,
        position: 'fixed',
        top:      'auto'
      })
    }
  }

  $(window).on('scroll resize', testScrollPosition)

  testScrollPosition();
})
```

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is a good foundation, but after scrolling past the div, and then back up, it would not be switched back to a fixed div, because `positionOffset` and `floatingOffset` were equal, and would not change.

I have [updated the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mFfM6/24/) to fix this. I also removed one of the divs, so you don't need to duplicate content.

```
$(function fixedUntilPoint() {

    var container = $('#container');
    var offsetContainer = container.offset().top;

    function adjustDivPosition() {

        var offsetFloat = $(document).scrollTop() + $(window).height() - container.outerHeight();

        if(offsetContainer <= offsetFloat){

            container.css({
                bottom:   'auto',
                position: 'absolute',
                top:      offsetContainer
            });

        } else {

            container.css({
                bottom:   0,
                position: 'fixed',
                top:      'auto'
            });

        }

    }

    $(window).on('scroll resize', adjustDivPosition)
        adjustDivPosition();

});
```